# How to find postgresql query which is consuming the most I/O

Tags: postgresql, io, query-performance

Lets say I have an `iotop` view like this:

[image: I/O top]

**How to find** the `SELECT` which is hitting the hard disk so heavy here?

Comment: https://statsbot.co/blog/postgresql-query-optimization/ check this blog , with EXPLAIN ANALYZE command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preparation:

Edit `postgresql.conf`:

- Add `pg_stat_statements` to `shared_preload_libraries` and restart PostgreSQL.
- Set `track_io_timing = on`.

Now let the workload run for a while.

Then find your I/O hog:

```
SELECT query
FROM pg_stat_statements
ORDER BY blk_read_time + blk_write_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```